# Binary classification of multivariate time series in the form of panel data using LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

## Problem definition

Dear community, I need your help in implementing an LSTM neural network for a classification problem of panel data using Keras. The panel data I am manipulating consists of ids (let's call it `id`), a timestep for each id (`t`), `n` time varying covariates and a binary outcome `y`. Each `id` contains a number of timesteps and for each timestep I have my covariates and a unique outcome (`0` or `1`). I have reason to believe that each covariate for each `id` can have a certain degree of autocorrelation and henceforth can be considered a *small* timeseries of `t` steps. For simplicity, I consider that each `id` has a fixed number of `t` observations) with `t` not a big number (about `10` or so).

## Data

Below is a toy example of what the data might look like in my case. In this example, the parameters are 2 individuals, 4 timesteps each, 4 covariates and each observation has a unique binary outcome. Covariates may be considered as (short) timeseries since they might be autocorrelated.

```py
print(df)

[out]:

            A          B            C           D        y
id   t                  
id1  1   1.054127   0.346052    1.091299    -0.058137   0.0
     2   0.621390   -0.204682   -1.056786   0.864572    0.0
     3   1.275124   2.473959    0.264029    -1.047810   0.0 
     4   -0.328441  -0.135891   0.148498    0.470876    1.0
id2  1   0.362969   0.777082    0.197423    -2.225296   0.0
     2   0.227134   0.086731    0.550267    -0.361482   0.0 
     3   0.223526   0.556242    -0.160042   0.675871    1.0
     4   0.070125   0.156659    -2.922709   -1.143887   1.0
```

I have reason to assume that, for `id1`, the target at timestep `4` is conditional on the three previous timesteps for that same individual (`id1`). In addition, The target variable `y` may contain more than one value of `1` for each individual (as outlined in the case of `id2` above). I do not have reason to believe that the data from an individual would affect the result of another (as with many behavior analysis scenarios since every individual is unique).

## Prediction problem

What I would like to do is to predict a single outcome for a new individual for whom I have those 4 rows of observation. In other words, based on the historical data of an individual, I would like to know if said individual is likely to have an outcome `1` or `0`. If I understand correctly, this can be achieved using an LSTM (alternatively, an RNN) with some data manipulation.

## Things I have tried so far

- To start simple, I have tried aggregating every set of `id` rows into a single row with a single outcome and applied a typical statistical learning approach such as boosted trees and got a model as good as random.
- I looked into shaping it as a survival analysis problem, in vain. I would not be interested in any estimation of a survival function unlike tutorials on how to handle panel data in the medical field (nor would I have access to such data).
- I have tried reshaping my data such that the input is a 3D array in the form of `[observations, timesteps, features]` where observations are unique `id`s for an LSTM like so in python :

```py
# separate into features and target
df_feat = df.drop("y", axis = 1)
df_target = df[["y"]]

# get reshaped values for 3D tensor
n_samples = len(df_feat.index.get_level_values('id').unique().tolist())
n_timesteps = 4
n_features = df_feat.shape[1]

# reshape input array to be 3D
X_3D = df_feat.to_numpy().reshape(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)
print(X_3D.shape)

[out]:
(2, 4, 4)
```

However, at this point I get confused as to what my learning instances for the LSTM are and what the outcome `y` should be shaped like. I have tried having a shape like one outcome per training instance by taking only the last observation for each `id` (so `y=[1,1]` and `y.shape = (2,)` in the toy example above) which technically makes an LSTM script run... but does not capture prior information. Below is the code for such LSTM:

```py
def train_lstm(X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid, save_name='best_lstm.h5'):

    # starts a sequential model
    model = Sequential()
    
    # add first lstm hidden layer with 64 units and default keras params
    model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    
    # add a second hidden lstm layer with 128 units and default keras params
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))
    
    # add one last hidden layer
    model.add(LSTM(64))
    
    # add one dense layer with 2 units and a sigmoid activation function
    model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    
    # define adam optimiser with learning rate
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01)
    
    # compile model with binary cross entropy as loss function and accuracy as metrics
    model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'binary_crossentropy',  metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    # define early stopping and best model checkpoint parameters
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'min', verbose = 0, patience = 20)
    mc = ModelCheckpoint(save_name, monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max', verbose = 0, save_best_only = True)
    
    # train the model using fit method (target vector is one-hot encoded as required by keras)
    history = model.fit(X_train, tf.one_hot(y_train, depth = 2),
                        validation_data = (X_valid, tf.one_hot(y_valid, depth = 2)),
                        epochs = 100, callbacks = [es, mc])
    
    return history
```

It runs and it makes predictions the way I want them to (for one `id` of previous history, we can predict one outcome) but results in poor performance since it fails to capture outcomes prior to the last.

- I have carefully read and followed this nicely written [medium](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/lstm-with-keras-data-reshaping-in-many-to-one-architecture-c7d3669e3a5c) article by Alexander Laskorunsky which remotely resembles what I am trying to do, and slides the window of K-length frames to capture the prior outcomes (and not just the last as I have done which makes more sense). However, in Alexander's case, he does not consider panel data but rather a multivariate timeseries classification that uses n_timesteps to predict the target using all predictors and all rows even if it overlaps (so **not** using panel data).

## Questions

- Am I right to believe that I need a many to one LSTM architecture?
- How may I divide and reshape training and testing samples such that a new, previously unseen individual which would not be related in any way to other `id`s can be classified?
- Should each `id` be considered as one sample / training instance? Should each `id` be split into training and testing sets and concatenate all training and testing sets to feed to an LSTM architecture?
- Would you be so kind as to provide code snippets on how to correctly split and reshape my data as well as a simple LSTM architecture using keras (or maybe modify my own function above in case I coded it wrong)? No need for basic preprocessing and encoding variables.

Any help or advice / tutorials / articles regarding what architecture is most suitable for that kind of problem is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does these help https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series and https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_from_scratch/. Thanks!